# Table Cell border on top of Table Row border when border-collapse is used

Tags: css

Is it possible to put table cell border on top of table row border if `border-collapse: collapse`? is set? Currently if I add and change a border color of table cell, its not visible because table row border is on top of it.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Always provide the latter, when you are asking this kind of question. (Yes, even in a case like this, that might seem trivial to you. Apart from that their _might_ be significant specifics that we can't get from just your verbal explanation alone, it is much more efficient, if you create a proper example of the situation _once_, instead of having everyone here willing to try and help, create one on their own.)